# why mathematica outputs "True" sometimes in outputs that are conditional to mean "in all other cases"?

Tags: piecewise, language-design

consider this simple Input:

```
Probability[g <= m && m <= -g + 1,
  {m, g} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, gg}}]]
```

which generates a piecewise continuous function:

$$\begin{cases}
1-gg & gg\le\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{4\,gg} & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$

My question is: why does mathematica outputs `True` rather that `gg>1/2`?

Comment: Because it is the default case, and while `g <= 1/2` partitions the space into only two sections,  consider the piecewise function found in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754414/198315). Overall, it is just simpler to have a default that is always run if no others match.

Comment: Note further that the actual output has the form `Piecewise[{{1 - gg, gg <= 1/2}}, 1/(4*gg)]` (execute `Probability[g <= m && m <= -g + 1, {m, g} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, gg}}]] // InputForm` to see).

Comment: I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't like the output format for `Piecewise` because it contains the default choice `True`, you may find it clearer to bring the output into a form that uses `ConditionalExpression` as follows:

```
p = Probability[
   g <= m && m <= -g + 1, {m, g} \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, gg}}]];

probability /. Solve[probability == p, probability, Reals]
```

> $$\left\{ \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[1-\text{gg},\text{gg}<\frac{1}{2}\right],\text{Conditional Expression}\left[\frac{1}{4\text{gg}},\text{gg}>\frac{1}{2}\right]\right\} $$